# Import data from .txt file and define x and y variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-import

I'm new to Python and I need to import data that is space separated.

The data looks something like this:

```
Title one

Title two

Title three

Title four

 1.2944870E-03  7.1226442E-01

 3.8834610E-03  8.3775342E-01

 6.4724353E-03  1.0313828E+00

 9.0614092E-03  7.7915078E-01

 2.2006279E-02  1.1677371E+00
```

I need to skip the first 4 lines during import.

So far I have this:

```
# Get .txt file
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Two Column txt","*.txt"),("Any text file","*.*")])

# Read the data
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(file_path,skiprows=4)
```

After importing with pd.read_csv the data cames as [*x*_amount of rows, 1 column].
I would like to know if anyone can tell me how to separate this and assign the first column to *X* and the second column to *Y*

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is space-separated then you should override the default comma-separated parsing using `sep=' '`. In order to provide your own headers you can use the `header` and `names` parameters:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=' ', skiprows=8, header=None, names=['X','Y'])
```

Comment: Hello,

With your line the data cames out like this
'
              X          Y

NaN 0.011650 NaN   0.685272

    0.014239 NaN   0.725674

    0.016828 NaN   0.747055

    0.019417 NaN   0.848044'

Comment: @ManuelOliveira What was your input file like? It may be related to the first 4 lines which you want to skip. My example was fitted to the sample you provided. If the titles look different then maybe you should remove them before importing to Pandas (e.g. using `tail -n +5 file_with_header.csv > file_without_header.csv`)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the file with

`data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\s+', skiprows=4, header=None, names=['X','Y'])`

Then I got the variables separated with:

`X=data['X']
Y=data['Y']`

Thank you all for the help.